# Why does Hibernate use MCoordinate instead of Coordinate?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgis

I'm using Hibernate Spatial in combination with Postgis and Java Spring Boot.

When my service starts pulling records from the database everything works fine, but the code ends up in `org.hibernate.spatial.jts.mgeom.MCoordinate`.
I would like to use default measure-less Coordinates instead, because other components of my application are not used to work with MCoordinate (and M-like geometries).

I guess it is a dependency issue? What should I have done differently?

Info:

**DATABASE** Postgres, Postgis; In my database I have a `GEOMETRY` field.

*dialect* `org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect`

**ENTITY** In my domain class I have the following:

```
@Column(name="myfield", columnDefinition="Geometry")
@Type(type="org.hibernate.spatial.GeometryType")
private Polygon myField;
```

**MAVEN**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.4-1201-jdbc41</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
        <version>4.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgis</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgis</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgis</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgis-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I don't have any knowledge about this extension, but are you trying to solve a non-problem? According to the Javadoc of MCoordinate: _While this class extends the Coordinate class, it can be used seamlessly as a substitute in the event that the Measure value is not used. In these cases the Measure value shall simply be Double.NaN_.

Comment: I use another library that was built for Coordinate implementation and not for MCoordinate implementation. `getDimension()` returns 4 instead of 3 now. So, I wanted to understand why this extra dimension is added. The code breaks now.